# Executing simple code on secondary processors, Pre-boot or in DOS

Tags: multiprocessing, bare-metal

On AMD-64 (family 15h) in barebone legacy mode - such as pre-booting, or in DOS - 
I wish to momentarily 'awake' each application processor in turn, have it run a (very short) sequence of instructions, and put it back to its previous waiting or sleeping state.

For specifics, I want each processor to 'WrMSR' some microcode update blob, newer than what's currently carved in BIOS. But the question can be, more generally : how to awake processor number N, set its state (CS:rIP) so it executes a prepared thread of instructions from DRAM and finally goes back to 'sleep' quietly?

This should be done with the lightest possible of machineries, in real mode as far as possible, using no "ACPI" tables, helpers, and stuff ! Also, for the kind of very basic and short tasks envisioned, the app processors would not need to serve hardware interrupts, so, I guess, no special APIC setup is needed.

I'd appreciate a sketch of the essential steps, with assembler or pseudo-code, and or pointers to relevant documentation or example code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is interesting but since you're asking for a complete solution to your problem, it is likely going to attract negative votes. Why don't you give it a go, write some code, and if you encounter issues share them here? Someone will surely help you. In the meanwhile please have a read of [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks, Michal. Actually I am not asking for a complete solution, rather for being pointed to documentation and or examples relating to the problem which I have tried to explain. Can you help me make the question better ? I am used to programming bare-bones systems, including the flashing of custom hobby firmware into BIOS "ROM"s - only I'm late to the multiprocessor game - this is the  first 64-bit and multicore CPU I have owned.

Comment: I understand your intentions. Still, not exactly typical for this forum. There are other forums in the stackexchange universe that might be more suitable, such as https://electronics.stackexchange.com. To make your question more Stack-Overflowy, you could perhaps pivot it around the **How to awake processor number N, set its state (CS:rIP) so it executes a prepared thread of instructions from DRAM and finally goes back to 'sleep' quietly...?** and add whatever code or sketches you have covered so far.